# Using DSolve for integro-differential equation $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f =hf+ \int \mathrm {d} i\, h f$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Edit Apr 28** Wolfram Support confirmed that `DSolve` behavior is unexpected and escalated to developers, Case 5025062. Meanwhile, I'm interested in a work-around or an alternative way to solve this with Mathematica.

---

DSolve fails to give expected solution for integro-differential equation of the following form.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t, i) =a h(i) f(t, i) + b h(i) \int \mathrm {d} i_1\, h(i_1) f(t, i_1)$$

IE, solving for $f$ using DSolve and then plugging the solution back into the equation gives False as seen below. Any suggestion how to find a working solution?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
h = (i + 1)^-2;
inti[expr_] := Integrate[expr, {i, 0, Infinity}];
eqn = D[f[i, t], t] == h f[i, t] + h inti[h f[i, t]];
sol = DSolveValue[{eqn, f[i, 0] == 1}, f[i, t], {i, t}]
f0 = Function @@ {{i, t}, sol};

Print["Solution: ", f0[i, t]];
Print["Back-substitute: ", eqn0 = eqn /. f -> f0];
Print["Solution correct: ", eqn0 /. {i -> 2, t -> 3}]  (*False*)
```

This is the continuous analogue of the DPR1 problem described [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848).

NDSolve also doesn't give expected solution. It's solution appears identical to the one where you make substitution $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ h(i) f(t, i)=f(t, i)\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ h(i)$. However, this transformation gives a different problem

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
h = (i + 1)^-2;
inti[expr_] := Integrate[expr, {i, 0, Infinity}];
eqn = D[f[i, t], t] == -2 h f[i, t] + h inti[h f[i, t]];
solSto = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn, f[i, 0] == 1}, f[i, t], {t, 0, 10}, 
   i \[Element] ImplicitRegion[i > 0 && i < 10, i]];

eqn = D[f[i, t], t] == -2 h f[i, t] + h f[i, t];
solDet = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn, f[i, 0] == 1}, f[i, t], {t, 0, 10}, 
   i \[Element] ImplicitRegion[i > 0 && i < 10, i]];

solDet == solSto (* true, but this shouldn't be *)
ContourPlot[solSto, {i, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I can solve this differential equation numerically by discretizing, and solving discrete linear system using inverse Laplace transform, but that doesn't really scale past 10 dimensions

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 10;
h = (i + 1)^-2;
discretize[expr_] := Table[N@expr /. {i -> i0}, {i0, 0, d - 1}];
{f0$, h$} = discretize /@ {1, h};

A = -2 DiagonalMatrix[h$] + {h$}\[Transpose] . {h$};
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];

f$ = Function @@ {{t}, 
    InverseLaplaceTransform[Inverse[s*ii - A], s, t] . f0$};
sol = Table[f$[t], {t, 0, 10}]
ListContourPlot[sol]
```

Below you can see solution of NDSolve vs the expected one (from Laplace Transform)

[image]

Comment: I tried `Block[{h = Exp[-i]}, 
  ResourceFunction["TraceView"][solve[h], TraceInternal -> True]];` to navigate through the internal implementation but I did not see anything particularly instructive. Maybe I did not look well enough

Comment: An advantage of mathematical notations is that they allow to convey the statement unambiguously. But your writing is actually ambiguous.  It is not clear what equation are you actually trying to solve. Why not write definite integral as definite integral, and use different symbols for variables in different context? There is a good proof for what I said, as MA itself misunderstood you.

Comment: @yarchik I'm not much of a mathematician, but the Mathematica code should make the problem unambiguous, no? I believe it's a bug in Mathematica, the solution I get from DSolve doesn't satisfy the differential equation given to DSolve, edited example of clarity

Comment: Could you expand on your post a bit better so that we can have some of the insights that your work has provided you so far? that might help us futher.

Comment: @alex I've expanded the post with `NDSolve` and `InverseLaplaceTransform` approaches. Starting to suspect that this kind of equation is not supported by `DSolve` or `NDSolve`

Comment: As it stands, its is  abuse of notation. The integration variable must not be used outside the integral.  If the algebraical use   int f(i) di = F(i)  with F'=f is meant, extensive use of Derivative should be use, to clarify things: Derivative[0,1][f] = f + Derivative[-1,0] [ f[#1,#2] g[#1]&]. Translated to Integrate, include the limits and localize the summation variable i, di ->j , dj . To improve human readabiliy the dummy variables should resemble the global names.

Comment: @RolandF I respect your opinion. The code should make the problem unambiguous. Seemingly ambiguous notation is an aesthetic choice, I realize it's not prefered by everyone. Stephen Boyd calls it "evolved notation", more on this [here](https://yaroslavvb.medium.com/using-evolved-notation-to-derive-the-hessian-of-cross-entropy-loss-195f8c7b3a92)

Comment: It just is impossible  for ME, to reconstruct the mathemarical problem, if the code is more complicated to decipher than the problem stated in the much shorter standard notation.

Comment: @RolandF following terminology of your other comment, this is an instance of parabolic equations with integral operator kernel, where the kernel $A$ is a continuous analogue of diagonal+rank1 matrix $\operatorname{diag}h+h\otimes h$ (a separable term + a localized term?). Wondering if there's a continuous version of Woodbury identity I can use to solve this

Answer (score 4):

**modified**
Infinite integration range `{z,0,Infinity}` has to be numerically adapted!

**case `h=1/(1+x)^2,a=-2,b=1`**

```
h=1/(1+#)^2&;
a=-2;
b=1;
```

*Numerical solution(`NDSolve`, iteration `NestList` or `FixedPoint`)*

```
inf = 10000; (*~Infinity *)
nl = NestList[Function[{fa}, Block[{int, x, t },
int[t_?NumericQ]:=Block[{z}, NIntegrate[ h[z] fa[z, t], {z, 0, inf(* Infinity*) },Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]; 
NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 1][f][x,t] ==a h[x] f[x, t] + b h[x] int[t]   , f[x, 0] == 1}, 
f, {x, 0, inf }, {t, 0, 10}, MaxStepSize -> {100, Automatic} ] ]],
1 &(*Identity*), 5] ; 
Plot3D[nl[[-1]][x, t], {x, 0, 100}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, f[x, t]}]
```

[image]

**final modification (14.5.2023)**

The iterative numerical solution might be improved considerably with the tranformation `u->h[x], f[x,t]->fu[u=h[x],t]`

The integrodifferential equation transforms to

[image]

Numerical iteration now converges much faster.

```
nlu = NestList[
Function[{fa}, 
Block[{int, x, t},int[t_?NumericQ] := 
Block[{z}, NIntegrate[ 1/(2 Sqrt[z]) fa[z, t], {z, 0, 1 },  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0},PrecisionGoal -> 5,AccuracyGoal -> 10]];
NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 1][f][u, t] == a u f[u, t] + b u int[t], f[u, 0] == 1}, f, {u, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10} ]]], 1 &(*Identity*), 10]; // AbsoluteTiming (* 1.9s*)

Plot3D[nlu[[-1]][h[x] , t], {x, 0, 10 }, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange ->All,MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, f[x, t]},PlotPoints-> 100]MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, f[x, t]},PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

**This solution is nearly identical to the solution found by Laplacetransformation !**

**end of final modification (14.5.2023)**

*Analytical solution(powerseries)*

Integrating the integrodifferentialequation vs time , thereby considering the ic `f[x,0]==1`, gives

[image]

fixedpoint equation

```
F = Function[{x, t}, 
Evaluate[1 + a h[x] Integrate[  #[x, \[Tau]] , {\[Tau], 0, t}] + b h[x]Integrate[h[z] #[z, \[Tau]], {z, 0, Infinity}, {\[Tau], 0, t}]]] &    

fp = FixedPoint[F, 1 &, 5]
Collect[fp[x, t], t, Expand]
    (*
1 - t/(1 + x)^2 + t^2 (1/(1 + x)^4 - 1/(6 (1 + x)^2)) + 
 t^4 (1/(3 (1 + x)^8) - 1/(18 (1 + x)^6) - 13/(540 (1 + x)^4) - 323/(
    22680 (1 + x)^2)) + 
 t^5 (-(2/(15 (1 + x)^10)) + 1/(45 (1 + x)^8) + 13/(1350 (1 + x)^6) + 
    323/(56700 (1 + x)^4) + 6647/(1701000 (1 + x)^2)) + 
 t^3 (-(2/(3 (1 + x)^6)) + 1/(9 (1 + x)^4) + 13/(270 (1 + x)^2))
*)
```

From this result one might guess the general form of the solution f[x,t]

[image]

The coefficients `c[k,j]` follow from equation `null==0` comparing powers of t

```
solF = Function[{x, t}, 1 + Sum[t^k c[k, j] (1 + x)^(-2  j ), {k, 1,n}, {j, 1, k }]]
null = Collect[1 + a h[x] Integrate[  solF[x, \[Tau]] , {\[Tau], 0, t}] +b h[x] Integrate[h[z] solF[z, \[Tau]], {z, 0, Infinity}, {\[Tau], 0, t}] - solF[x, t], t, FullSimplify]
(*-((t (1 + c[1, 1]))/(1 + x)^2) + 
(t^2 ((-5 + x (2 + x)) c[1, 1] -6 ((1 + x)^2 c[2, 1] + c[2, 2])))/(6 (1 + x)^4) +
...*)
```

`{c[1, 1] -> -1, c[2, 1] -> -(1/6), c[2, 2] -> 1,...}`

Comment: Very interesting! (btw, the interesting cases are a=-2, b=1 and a=-2, b=0, they correspond to fully stochastic vs. fully deterministic version of [DPR1 problem](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)

Comment: Ok I' ll modify my answer to the case `a=-2,b=1`!

Comment: thanks, will dig into it. It's interesting that you integrate over time rather than take Laplace Transform. For the discrete version of the problem I can apply Sherman-Woodbury to get a [simple formula](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-field-equation.nb) for laplace transform of $g(t)=\int \mathrm{d}i\ f(i, t)$, $$\mathcal{L}(g)(s)=\langle 1/z,1\rangle + \frac{b}{1-b\langle h/z,h\rangle} \langle h/z,1\rangle^2\\
z=s-a h$$

Comment: In your first `solf`, why do you call `NDSolve` as a subroutine to fixed point iteration rather than just using `NDSolve` directly?

Comment: It's an iterative solution where I evaluate the integralpart of the ode with the last iteration. The solutions `nl` should converge against the unknown solution(hopefully)

Comment: Why is it 2D integral? In original formula, it integrates over $i$ dimension only

Comment: Sorry, I modified my answer

Comment: I think this gives incorrect result. Try $a=-2,b=0$, a unique solution is $\exp(-2h(x)t)$, but your code gives a polynomial that eventually becomes negative

Comment: I checked case `a=0,b=2` which gives the correct solution found in  [How to solve ∂∂tf(i,t)=bh(i)∫∞0dih(i)f(i,t)
with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284530/how-to-solve-frac-partial-partial-t-fi-t-b-hi-int-0-infty-mathrm)

Comment: Here's me [checking](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-ulrich-solution.nb) your solution for $a=0,b=2$. True solution is exponential in $t$, but your solution is polynomial

Comment: That's ok: My solution is the finite approximation of exp , because I took a finite iteration up to order n=5 !

Comment: I see. It seems I get similar form if I substitute  5th order Taylor expansion of exp into true solution (but coefficients are different)

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann:  when I copy and paste the numeric code it's missing a closing bracket for the Block command.  When I add it, then  NIntegrate encounters non-numeric values even if I replace a and b with -2 and 1 respectively.  I'm using 13.2.

Comment: Also, I had dropped the number of iterations down to 2 in the case above.  Maybe needs more than 2.  Running it now with original 5.

Comment: @josh Thanks.  I modified the code!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks, that looks more like the truth. So I take it NDSolve just doesn't support integro-differential equations with unknown integrand then

Comment: @UlrichNeumann looks like this differential equation has a [simple solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694070/998) in terms of inverse laplace transform

Comment: Interesting link, but I didn't get the part "...integrating against h.." Have to check it after my holidays

Comment: You solve for $f(x, t)$, the thing I care about in the end is $g(t)=\int \mathrm{d}x\ h(x) f(x, t)$. Laplace transform of $g(t)$ is known, but inverting it [is hard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284839/tricky-inverselaplacetransform-problem)

Comment: After Laplace transformation next step in the link: ...integrating against h..

Comment: @UlrichNeumann that's because two integrals commute. They first get Laplace transform of $f(x,t)$, integrating this gives laplace transform of $g(t)=\int \mathrm{d}x\ h(x)f(x,t)$. $g(t)$ is ultimately what I need

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov First integration gives an integral equation for the Laplacetransform F[x,s], clear. Why should  second integration along x(not s or t!) give Laplacetransform of g[t]??? Why should integral part disappear?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann ok, I was confused too, but the author just updated the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694070/998). The trick is to make "self consistent equation"-- solve for F, integrate, solve for F again

Comment: Thanks for the final update. The change of variables is a cool trick

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible,   you try to solve someting like the damped linear  equation with

```
 f'[t] == - λ  f[t] + h[t] f[t]  ->  Log[f[t]]] == \int^t( h[s] -λ ds 

  f[t] == f[0] Exp[-λ t +\int_0^t h[s]ds ]
```

Under integral transforms the product maps to a convolution integral. I had the suspect `h`  as   `1/(I+s)` that is the Laplace transform of `e^-t`

Comment: As far as I can say, `f` is a function of two arguments. In your solution it is a function of just one.