# How to solve $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(i,t) =b h(i) \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} i\, h(i) f(i,t)$ with Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given $b$, $h(i)$, how do I solve the following in Mathematica for initial value $f(i,0)=1$?
$$\begin{equation}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(i,t) =b h(i) \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} i\, h(i) f(i,t)\label{eq}\tag{1}\end{equation}$$

An internet user [says](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686487/solving-frac-partial-partial-t-f-hf-int-mathrm-d-i-h-f#comment9914864_4686487) that solution is $f(i,t)=1+\frac{1}{h_2} (e^{bh_2 t} - 1)h(i)$. I suspect it is incorrect.

Any tips?

---

What I tried:

### DSolve: returns unevaluated

Let $h(i)=(1+i)^{-2}, b=1$, we can use `DSolve`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
h = (i + 1)^-2;
inti[expr_] := Integrate[expr, {i, 0, Infinity}];
eqn = D[f[i, t], t] == h inti[h f[i, t]];
DSolveValue[{eqn, f[i, 0] == 1}, f[i, t], {t, i}]
```

[image]

Meanwhile, the following `DSolve` succeeds but the output doesn't satisfy \eqref{eq}, similar to issue [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284257/217)

`DSolveValue[{eqn, f[i, 0] == 1}, f[i, t], {i, t}]`

### NDSolve: produces numerical noise

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
h = (i + 1)^-2;
inti[expr_] := Integrate[expr, {i, 0, Infinity}];
eqn = D[f[i, t], t] == h inti[h f[i, t]];

numSteps = 100;
maxDim = 10;
solSto = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn, f[i, 0] == 1}, f[i, t], {t, 0, numSteps}, 
   i \[Element] ImplicitRegion[i >= 0 && i <= maxDim, i]];
ContourPlot[solSto, {i, 0, maxDim}, {t, 0, numSteps}]

func[i0_] := Block[{i = i0, t = numSteps}, solSto]
Plot[{h, func[i]}, {i, 0, 9}]
```

[image]

### InverseLaplaceTransform: slow

Discretizing at $n$ points and applying inverse Laplace transform gives something that's within a constant factor to the solution provided. However it

1. Doesn't give me the missing constant factor
2. Is very slow. I believe it does $O(n^3)$ matrix inversion, and then issues $O(n^2)$ calls to inverse Laplace transform.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 10;
h = (i + 1)^-2;
discretize[expr_] := Table[N@expr /. {i -> i0}, {i0, 0, d - 1}];
{f0$, h$} = discretize /@ {1, h};

A = {h$}\[Transpose] . {h$};
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];

f$ = Function @@ {{t}, 
    InverseLaplaceTransform[Inverse[s*ii - A], s, t] . f0$};
sol = Table[f$[t], {t, 0, 10}];
ListContourPlot[Re@sol]
ListPlot[{Re@Last@sol, h$}, MultiaxisArrangement -> All, 
 Filling -> Bottom]
```

[image]

Comment: Using your reference in the Mathematica forum and letting $f(i,t)=1+g(t)h(i)$ I get a different answer than above:  $$\displaystyle f(i,t)=1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^2}\left(3 e^{b h_2 t}-\frac{1}{h_2}\right)$$ with $\displaystyle h_2=\int_0^{\infty} h(i)^2 di=1/3$ and this solution satisfies the IDE and the initial conditions $f(i,0)=1$.

Comment: @josh actually that appears to be the same, since 3 is $\frac{1}{h_2}$. How did you solve it?

Comment: The solution I get by heuristically extrapolating from discrete time version of the problem is $$f(i, t)=1+\frac{h_1}{h_2}(e^{bh_2 t} - 1)$$ where $h_1=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ h(i)$

Comment: Ok thanks.  Didn't see that.  I posted how I did it below.

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution of

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t) =b h(x) \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z) f(z,t)$$

could be obtained using the Ansatz $f(x,t)=g(x)+h(x)F(t)$. We have
$$
\frac{d}{d t}F(t)=b \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z)^2F(t)+b\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z)g(z).
$$
Denote
$$
H=b \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z)^2,\\
G=b\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z)g(z).
$$
and solve the resulting ODE for F(t)
$$
\frac{d}{d t}F(t)=HF(t)+G.
$$
What are the boundary conditions? From $(x,0)=1$ we infer
$$
g(x)+h(x)F(0)=1.
$$
From this equation follows
$$
F(0)=\frac{1-g(x)}{h(x)}.
$$
Thus, $g(x)=1-ch(x)$ and $F(0)=c$. Now

```
DSolveValue[{D[F[t], t] == H F[t] + G, F[0] == c}, F[t], t]
```

leading to
$$
F(t)=\frac{c H e^{H t}+G e^{H t}-G}{H}.
$$
Also, per definition
$$
G=b\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z)(1-ch(z))=K-cH,\\
K=b\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z).
$$

The full solution is then
$$
f(x,t)=1-\frac{K}{H}h(x)+h(x)\frac{K}{H} e^{H t},\\
H=b \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z)^2,\\
K=b\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z).
$$

**Verification:**

$$
\text{lhs}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x,t)=h(x)K e^{H t}.\\
 b \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z) f(z,t)=
b \int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z) \left(1-\frac{K}{H}h(z)+h(z)\frac{K}{H} e^{H t}\right)=K-\frac{K}{H}H+\frac{HK}{H}e^{H t}=Ke^{H t},\\
\text{rhs}=b h(x)\int_0^\infty \mathrm {d} z\, h(z) f(z,t)=h(x)Ke^{H t},\\
\text{lhs}=\text{rhs}.
$$

Comment: It's weird that there's not enough boundary conditions given that the discrete version of this problem is $f_{t+1}-f_t=bhh^T f_t$ which is uniquely defined by value of $f_0$. We can define corresponding problem for finer discretization, which will also be unique, hence I expect the continuous limit to be unique

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yes, you are right, the constant $c$ can be eliminated from the final result, see my edit.

Comment: neat! I wonder if this method can also be used to solve https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284257/using-dsolve-for-integro-differential-equation-frac-partial-partial-t-f-h

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I tried, but so far no progress...

Comment: I made some progress solving the discrete version for $h(t)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}i\ f(i,t)$. Using Sherman-Morrison formula, I [verified](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-field-equation.nb) the following: $$\mathcal{L}(g)(s)=\langle 1/z,1\rangle + \frac{b}{1-b\langle h/z,h\rangle} \langle h/z,1\rangle^2$$ where $z=s-ah$, $1$ refers to vector of ones, $x/y$ is pointwise division of vectors

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a the standard problem of a parabolic evolution equations, depending on the integral kernel h.

Your discrete comment's definition translates to

```
 f[t+1,n]-f[t,n] = b Sum[ Sum[ h[n,m] h[k,m], {m} ]  f[t,k],{k}]
```

(don't be sparing at spaces, at least not at implicit "*"'s)

The continuous t,k limit is

```
dt d/dt f[t,k] = b Integrate[#,{k'}]& [Integrate[ h[k',k''] h[k'',k'] f[t,k'], {k''}]]  
== Integrate[  K[k,k'] f[t,k'], {k'}  ]
```

with

```
K[k,k'] == K[k',k]
```

a symmetric kernel.

A symmetric kernel K defines a selfadjoint linear operator A, written as a linear function

```
f' =  A [f]  ->  f[t] = Exp[A t][f[0]]
```

if A has negative spectrum only, the matrix Exp converges for all t > 0. It's of course a delicate problem because nth-powers of integrals are in fact  n-dimensional integrals over powers of f

```
    1/2! Integral[f[x],{x}]^2 == 
       1/2!Integral[f[x],{x}]Integral[f[y],{y}]
    =1/2!Integral[f[x]f[y],{x,y}]]
```

Eg if

```
K = delta(k-k') k'^2  

 f'[t][k] = -k^2 f[t][k]
```

that is the Fourier transform of

```
g'[t][x]  = D[g[t][x],{x,2}]
```

by

```
f[x] == Integrate[Exp[I k x]g[k],{k}]
```

Comment: Interesting....I don't quite get the point of $g$ in the last 2 equations, is that the continuous analogue of formula $f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(s I - A)$ in the discrete-time evolution $f(t+1)-f(t)=A f(t)$?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming solution $f(i,t)=1+g(t)h(i)$ and substituting into the IDE:
$$
\begin{align}
h(i)\frac{dg}{dt}&=b h(i)\int_0^{\infty} h(i)\left(1+g(t)h(i)\right)di \\
&=b h(i)\left(\int_0^{\infty} h(i)di+g(t)\int_0^{\infty} (h(i))^2di\right)\\
&=b h(i)\left(1+g(t)h_2\right)
\end{align}
$$
So that
$$\displaystyle h(i)g'(t)=b h(i)\left(1+g(t)h_2\right)$$
Solving via Mathematica code:

```
theSol = DSolve[h[i] g'[t] == b h[i] (1 + g[t] h2), g[t], t][[1]]
gSol[t_] = g[t] /. theSol
(* -(1/h2) + E^(b h2 t) C[1] *)
```

then $\displaystyle g(t)=-\frac{1}{h2}+c_1 e^{bh_2 t}$ and therefore:
$$
f(i,t)=1+h(i)\left(-\frac{1}{h_2}+c_1 e^{bh_2 t}\right)
$$
and since $h_2=1/3$, we let $c_1=3$ since $f(i,0)=1$ or
$$
f(i,t)=1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^2}\left(3 e^{bh_2 t}-3\right)
$$
Plotting the solution for $b=2$:

```
b = 2;
h2 = 1/3;
fSol[i_, t_] := 1 + (-3 + 3 E^(b h2 t))/(1 + i)^2;
Plot3D[fSol[i, t], {i, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["i", 14, Bold, Black], 
   Style["t", 14, Bold, Black], Style["f", 14, Bold, Black]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems pretty clear `NDSolve` does not give correct result here, contacted support

Comment: Compared NDSolve to this solution [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-field-equation.nb), looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WDYN.png). May be missing some secret flags to make NDSolve work