# Tricky InverseLaplaceTransform problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Is there a way to get an expression for $g(t)$ defined as Laplace Transform below?
$$g(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{x^2 \tan^{-1} x}{x+\tan^{-1} x}\right](t)$$
where
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}$$

This gives symbolic solution to NDSolve problem solved numerically by Ulich [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284602/217), worked out by user [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694070/998)

Putting it into Mathematica gives an expression containing both $t$ and $s$

```
x = Sqrt[2/s];
InverseLaplaceTransform[(x^2 ArcTan[x])/(x + ArcTan[x]), s, t]
```

Comment: With version "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" this returns (after use of `Simplify`) `(4 - 4 E^(-2 t) + 4 t Log[8]^2 - 4 Log[1/8 (-2 - s)] + Log[1/8 (-2 - s)]^2 - 2 t Log[4096] Log[-2 - s] + 4 t Log[-2 - s]^2)/(2 t (-2 + Log[1/8 (-2 - s)])^2)` The presence of `s` in the result indicates that this is **wrong**.

Comment: I'm on very shaky ground here (mathematically), but it is possible to do a series expansion around `s==0`.  Can the transform be applied term by term in some way?

Comment: @mikado well, there this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m7Kd.jpg), from Ch 2 of "Numerical Methods For Inverse Laplace" [book](https://www.siirt.edu.tr/dosya/personel/laplace-siirt-2019320222328704.pdf), $\bar{f}$ refers to Laplace transform of $f$

Comment: @mikado The first obstacle of using this approach is finding symbolic expression for $\lambda_n$ in [Eq 2.40](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m7Kd.jpg). $g(t)$ comes from diff-eq corresponding to the DPR1 problem described in community [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2902848)

Comment: There exist formulas for Laplace transforms of functions of sqrt s, and the tan^.1 1/s =cot^-1 s. But the formula is an integral of the Laplace transform of f(s) with a Gaussian. Unfortunately Mathematica cannot perform the transform of the expression with arccot s nor the direct integral. So I don't expect a closed formula besides the usual series expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way.

I use **Post - Widder formula** to compute `InverseLaplaceTransform`.
$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[F(s)](t)=\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{\frac{\partial ^n}{\partial t^n}\left(t^{n-1}
   F\left(\frac{n}{t}\right)\right)}{\Gamma (n)}$$
I only use `n=20`, because I can't find closed-form for **n-th** derivative.

```
 g = (2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/s]])/(
 s (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/s] + ArcTan[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/s]]));
 U[t_] := InverseLaplaceTransform[g, s, N@t];
 F[s_] := (2 ArcTan[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/s]])/(
 s (Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/s] + ArcTan[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/s]]));
 G[t_, n_] := 1/Gamma[n]*D[t^(n - 1)*F[n/t], {t, n}]

 {Plot[{U[t], Evaluate@G[t, 1]}, {t, 0, 10}], Plot[{U[t], Evaluate@G[t, 20]}, {t, 0, 10}]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

would a numerical solution help?

```
f = x^2 ArcTan[x]/(x + ArcTan[x]) /. x -> Sqrt[2/s] // FullSimplify;
g = Table[{t, InverseLaplaceTransform[f, s, t]}, {t, 0.01, 10.,0.1}];
model = a*Exp[-b*t] + c;
fit = NonlinearModelFit[g, model, {a, b, c}, t];
Show[ListPlot[g], Plot[fit[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[fit["FitResiduals"],DataRange -> {0, 10}, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

Comment: so it's useful in a sense that the solution is clearly not exponential, I'm trying to figure out what the correct functional form is

Comment: The solution for closely related problem is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4 t}}$ so this may also be some kind of power law

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov A huge improvement is obtained with the `model = a - Exp[b/Sqrt[t]]`. Good luck!

Comment: interesting! If we extrapolate, this will underestimate the true value, while power-law fit overestimates, so the solution is neither pure exponential nor power law

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov Please consider that the solution only applies to the numerically calculated range, i.e. in this case for t in the interval [0.01,10]. For this range, the solution is only an approximation and by no means a general analytical solution.

Answer (score 4):

Defining

```
approx[n_] := approx[n] = 
  InverseLaplaceTransform[Normal[Series[expr, {s, ∞, n}]],s, t]
```

I find that the results are computed quite quickly.

This seems to give consistent values for small values of `t`

For example

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[approx[i], {i, 16, 32}]], {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Transform results]

I've no idea if the results are mathematically valid or helpful to you.

Comment: Interesting ! I wonder if this representation is connected to the series in the theorem, writing expression as infinite partial fraction representation

Answer (score 1):

Hope I didn't misunderstand the question:

If only numerical solution is asked for try

```
invLaplace[ t_?NumericQ] := 
InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(s/2 + Sqrt[s]/(Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]])),s, t]

Plot[invLaplace[t], {t, 0.001, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like correct graph. This is another example of the integro-differential equation you provided Nested DSolve solution for earlier, the technique to get Laplace Transform of solution is documented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694070/998), I'm was looking to understand how fast the solution decays to zero

Comment: But the original   integro-differential equation leads to a more complicated [x-dependent inverse Laplace-Transformation](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/ulrich.neumann/Published/invLaplace.nb%20.nb)   I think

Comment: They are slightly different (due to different values of $a,b$) but you can see that asymptotically they both have $1/\sqrt{t}$ decay