# Can an InverseLaplaceTransform of this expression be computed?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm looking to compute the Inverse Laplace Transform of the expression below for $0\le b\le 1$

$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s} \left(1-\frac{1}{4} b \left(2-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)\right)\right)}$$

I found some ways to compute this for $b=0$, is there a way to do this for any other values of $b$, such as $b=1$?

Here's the computation for $b=0$

```
Block[{$Assumptions = {}, b = 0},
 InverseLaplaceTransform[ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]]/(
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
   s] (1 - 1/4 b (2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]]))), s, t]
 ]
```

Background: this is symbolic formula for $E_h[f]$ where f is solution of differential equation in this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284602/217) for $a=-2$

Comment: Hmmmm.... is there an identity that allows you to substitute $y = \sqrt{\frac{2}{s}}$ to simplify matters?  When $b=0$:  $$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t}\right)}{2 \sqrt{t}}$$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork   Good question, in other words, if we do this substitution in Laplace domain, what's the effect on time domain? Curious about that too

Comment: @DavidG.Stork btw how did you get this expression? Default `InverseLaplaceTransform` [doesn't work out of the box](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285293/inverselaplacetransform-producing-unexpected-imaginary-terms)

Comment: I set $b=0$ and used `InverseLaplaceTransform` (without the unneeded Block, Assumptions, etc.).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ok, looks like a regression in 13.2.1   version, since the following gives verbose result with non-zero imaginary part `InverseLaplaceTransform[ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s]), s, t]`, submitted to support

Comment: If you have difficulty solving it algebraically, then consider evaluating the  associated contour integral numerically.  I've found this approach adequate in the past although in your case I suspect will have to deal with an analytically-continuous path over the inverse functions.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 13.2.0.0 gives an answer if you avoid the special case of b=0.

```
Block[{$Assumptions = {0<b<=1}},
InverseLaplaceTransform[ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s] (1 - 1/4 b (2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]]))), s, t]]

(*((8 - 4*b)*Sqrt[Pi/2]*Erf[Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[t]])/
   (Sqrt[t]*(4 + b*(-2 + Log[8]) - b*Log[-2 - s])²)*)
```

For b=0, The Block you posted gives:

```
(*(-(Pi*Erf[Sqrt[2]*Sqrt[t]]) - 
   4*I*t*HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3/2, 2}, -2*t])/
   (2*Sqrt[2*Pi]*Sqrt[t])*)
```

Comment: I get this in V13.2.1, too.

Comment: There shouldn't be s in the answer though

Answer (score 1):

Here's the beginnings of a numeric approach.  Will need to confirm singular points, and convergence speed along the contour.

Firse consider the inverse transform contour integral:

$$
\displaystyle \mathscr{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}(t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i }\lim_{\beta \to\infty}\mathop{\int}_{\gamma-i\beta}^{\gamma+i\beta} e^{st} \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s} \left(1-\frac{1}{4} b \left(2-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s} \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)\right)\right)} d\beta
$$
with $s=\gamma+i\beta$ and $\gamma$ greater than the real part of all singularities of the integrand.  So that as far as I can tell, the only singularity is the origin but need to investigate this more to make sure the path is correct.  So let $\gamma=1$.

After testing a few terms in detail, the convergence appears to be quick along the path.  So I'll just integrate it from $\beta=-100$ to $\beta=100$ but will need to more study this.

**Edit:  forgot the i from the differential ds in initial post.  Note this cancels the i in coefficient of integral.  Updated below**

**Edit2:  Made a mistake with the integrand.  Update 2 below.  Updated below**

**Edit3:  Third mistake with integrand.  Corrected below**

The following code is a comparison for the case of $b=0$ of the real numeric results to the analytic results given by David above as:
$$
\text{bZero(t)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi/2}\text{Erf}(\sqrt{2} \sqrt{t})}{2 \sqrt{t}}
$$

```
    f[s_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] = 
  ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/
     Sqrt[s]]/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
      s] (1 - 1/4 b (2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/Sqrt[s]])));

bZeroF[t_] := (Sqrt[Pi/2] Erf[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t]])/(2 Sqrt[t]);

lTable2D = Table[
   {theT, 
    1/(2 Pi )
      NIntegrate[f[s, 0] Exp[s theT] /. s -> 1 + I t, {t, -200, 200}]},
   {theT, 0.1, 5, 0.1}
   ];

 realData = {#[[1]], Re@#[[2]]} & /@ lTable2D;
lp1 = ListPlot[realData, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Numeric"}, {0.9, 0.9}]];
lp2 = Plot[Re@bZeroF[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Analytic"}, {0.9, 0.7}]];
Show[{lp1, lp2}]
```

[image]

Comment: There's just one pole at 0. This problem is analogous to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284839/tricky-inverselaplacetransform-problem . Maybe analytic exact solution is not possible, so was looking for analytic lower + upper bounds